# Star rating control in Titanium Alloy?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I need to get the feedback star ratings for 5 questions, I'm using titanium alloy mobile development. For the same reason I have used the star rating widget from the below link,

https://github.com/AppceleratorSolutions/AlloyWidgets/tree/master/starrating

From the above link there is only one set of stars, But I need to use the star ratings for 5 times. How can I do that. I need the following format

```
1. Question?

    *****
2. Question?

    *****
3. Question?

    *****
4. Question?

    *****
5. Question?

    *****
```

The widget is working fine but the stars are displaying only for one question, I need the stars for all the five questions, below is my current output,

[image]

questionnaire.xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="questionnaireWin" title="Plan India" platform="android,ios">
        <View id="header">
              <Label id="title">Feedback</Label>
        </View>

        <Label id="question1" class="question">1. Question 1?</Label>
         <Require type="widget" src="starrating" id="widget" name="widget" />

         <Label id="question2" class="question">2. Question 2?</Label>
         <Require type="widget" src="starrating" id="widget" name="widget" />  

         <Button class="button" onClick="submitRatings">Proceed</Button>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Though, I'm using widget twice it is showing only once. Please help how to do this?

Else any easy way to do this using any plugins or something esle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have required the same widget tow times using the same **id**. you should define different **id**.

```
<Alloy>
   <Window id="questionnaireWin" title="Plan India" platform="android,ios">
    <View id="header">
          <Label id="title">Feedback</Label>
    </View>

    <Label id="question1" class="question">1. Question 1?</Label>
     <Require type="widget" src="starrating" id="widget1" name="widget" />

     <Label id="question2" class="question">2. Question 2?</Label>
     <Require type="widget" src="starrating" id="widget2" name="widget" />  

     <Button class="button" onClick="submitRatings">Proceed</Button>

</Window>
```

and the in you js file initialize widget1 & widget2 ...

```
$.widget1.init();
$.widget2.init();
```

EDIT you can test this [example that i have created ...](https://github.com/LHIOUI/starRating)

Comment: I tried this, But that ID is mapped to widget. So it is throwing that "widget1" is not found error

Comment: previously it was only widget.xml, now I have added  widget1.xml,  widget2.xml,  widget3.xml,  widget4.xml in external widgets. Now it is working fine. But this coreeect way to do?

Comment: I assume that it is not the correct way to solve your problem. Even i have tested the solution when putting different id for widget required and it work very well ... you should review your js code ...

Comment: Also I have queries regarding database connection, Please give me suggestion for the following question,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973128/how-to-retrive-values-from-database-in-titanium-alloy

Comment: I want to use this starrating dynamically in list view for every list item I have to show star rating. My ListView is populated by JSON feed. How can I use this widget in this case? @Coyote

Comment: I think you can't do this using a ListView since you don't have any control overs listView item. But you can use tableView to do it.