# How to retrive values from Database in Titanium Alloy?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I'm new to Titanium API. I want to know how to retrieve values from DB and display in UI. I created a model and inserted a row. My code is as below,

**Model:**

```
var moment = require('alloy/moment');

exports.definition = {
    config : {
            "columns": {
            "id":"text",
            "LanguageName":"text"
            },
            "adapter": {
                "type": "sql",
                "collection_name": "UserLanguage"
            }
    },

    extendModel: function(Model) {      
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {

        });

        return Model;
    },

    extendCollection: function(Collection) {        
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {

        });

        return Collection;
    }
};
```

**View:**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="changeLangWindow" title="Plan India">
        <Picker id="langPicker">
            <PickerRow title="Select a Language"/>
            <PickerRow title="English"/>
            <PickerRow title="French"/>
            <PickerRow title="Spanish"/>
        </Picker>
        <Button class="button" onClick="saveLang">Proceed</Button>
        <Label class="question">Selected Language is: -------</Label>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**Controller:**

```
function saveLang() {

    var UserLang = Alloy.Collections.UserLanguage;

    // Create a new model for the todo collection
    var task = Alloy.createModel('UserLanguage', {
        id : '1',
        LanguageName : 'English'
    });

    // add new model to the global collection
      UserLang.add(task);

    // save the model to persistent storage
    task.save();

    // reload the tasks
     UserLang.fetch();

}
```

I want to select the value of "LanguageName" from "UserLanguage" model and display in the View that is in XML file.

Any suggestions with explanation please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// Try this code May be this is helpful for you.

```
if (Alloy.Collections.UserLanguage.length) {
     Alloy.Collections.UserLanguage.map(function(obj) {

        Ti.API.Log(" LanguageName "+ obj.get('LanguageName'));
        Ti.API.Log(" LanguageName "+ obj.id);

     });

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yeah, It is working. But How can I write the WHERE condition, Like select LanguageName where id=7;

Comment: Also How can we display the selected value on UI. that is how to pass selected value from js file to xml?

Comment: you can fetch like this through ID "var model = Alloy.Collections.UserLanguage.get("your id");"

Comment: If we get multiple values in select queries, How can we handle it?

Comment: If this answer is working or helpful for you. then accept this answer :) Thanks

Comment: Sure will accept your answer. But I have some queries please give some suggestions

Comment: How to display the selected value in UI?

Comment: From PickerView, you can get Value through addEventLister (Change listener). and display in Label.
in that function update you Label.text value with Selected Picker View value.

Comment: and Read this link for you another query for SQL Query : 
https://github.com/aaronksaunders/todolist.alloy/tree/master/app/controllers